# Mongodb createUser Exception

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb version 2.6.7 and getting following error.

```
> use admin
    switched to db admin
    > db.version();
    2.6.7
    > db.createUser({user: 'root', pwd: 'r00t', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'metadata_repo'}]});
    Tue Nov  3 18:43:06.765 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Property 'createUser' of object admin is not a function
    >
```

I'm connecting to mongod server from localhost with mongodb 2.4.5 shell. Can this affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's due to the versions mismatch.

MongoDB `2.4` only has the `addUser` shell method.

In MongoDB `2.6` the `addUser` shell method has been deprecated in favor of `createUser`.

In MongoDB `3.0`, `addUser` shell method has been completely removed.

You have three options here:

1. Connect via MongoDB `2.6` (`3.0` also should work) shell and issue `createUser`.
2. Issue `addUser` from your current `2.4` shell (not recommended)
3. Instead of calling `createUser` method, issue [a create user command](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/command/createUser/). This should work even when using `2.4` shell and `2.6` database.

Answer (score 0):

`db.createUser` is a MongoDB 3.* method, you should try `db.addUser` [(definition)](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.addUser/).